# Do $f(g)$ and $f(g(x))$ represent the same thing, in general?

Tags: functions, notation

Given $f = f(x)$ and $g = g(x)$, I was wondering if one usually distinguishes between $y_1 = f(g)$ and $y_2 = f(g(x))$?

E.g. If $f = e^{x}$ and $g = \sqrt{x}$, then

- $y_1 = f(g) = e^{g}$, where we know $g = \sqrt{x}$, and
- $y_2 = f(g(x)) = e^{\sqrt{x}}$

I realized that I generally do distinguish between these two, with the understanding that for any value $y_2(x_o)$ there exists $g_o \in \mathcal{D}(y_1)$ (*i.e.* in the domain of $y_1$) such that $y_2(x_o) = y_1(g_o)$; however, sometimes I do treat them as equivalent, to keep my work a bit cleaner (but only after specifying that the inner function is a function of $x$).

Is there any technical language for describing $f(g)$ and $f(g(x))$ that addresses the "same-but-different" relationship between them?

Comment: It depends on the authors intent. Assuming $g: X \to Y $ and $f:Y \to Z$ functions of sets, then $f(g)$ generally has no meaning save as a shorthand for  $f \circ g: X \to Z$, which is a function. Conversely, for $x \in X$, $f(g(x))$ is a point in $Z$. In this sense $y_1 \neq y_2$. However, it is common to use $f(g(x))$ as a shorthand for the function which takes any  $x \in X$ to $f$ applied to $g(x)$. Here $x$ is acting more  as a variable. In this sense $y_1 = y_2$. You are looking at the special case where $X = Y = Z = \mathbb R$

Comment: Please clarify your term $\mathcal D(y_1)$, I do not believe it is standard notation but it seems you mean the domain of $y_1$.

Comment: @user2628206 Thank you for the detailed reply (I clarified the notation; I did indeed mean the domain). When you say "*then () generally has no meaning save as ...*" does this hold even if we say something like "Let $g = g(x) = \left<\textit{some expression}\right>$"? In that case, wouldn't $g$ be considered a variable? If so, then would $f(x)$ and $f(g)$ mean the same thing (assuming the mapping between sets, you gave, above)?

Comment: For the first comparison you made, *i.e.* $f(g)$ *vs.* $f(g(x))$ is that distinction just the difference between $f \circ g$ and $f \circ g(x)$? *i.e.* between "the function" and "the function of ..."? *i.e.* one represents the general mapping, the other represents a value?

Comment: There is a very subtle difference between $f$ and $f(x)$ and I don't think it'd be appropriate to ever write "$f = f(x)$".  They refer to the same thing but we we have different intent and usage when we use one over the other.  Although it would be okay to use $f(g(x))$ to refer to $f\circ g$ in much the same way as we use $f(x)$ to refer to $f$ it'd be wrong and confusing to use $f(g)$ to refer to $f\circ g$.  It is possible to have a function that maps *functions* to values and if $f$ is such a function $f(g)$ would mean the output of what function $g$ is mapped to. Very different concept.

Comment: For gits and shiggles.  Let $X = \{\sin, \cos,  x^2+7\}$ and $Y=\{green,yellow, blue\}$.  Let $f_1:X\to Y$ via $\sin\mapsto green;\cos\mapsto yellow; x^2+7\mapsto blue$.  Let $g\in X$ then $f_1(g)$ will be the value of $green, yellow, blue$ that the function $g$ is mapped to.  Example $f(\cos)= yellow$.  Now let $f_2:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.  Then $f_2(g(x))=f_2\circ g(x)$ and $f_2(\cos(x))=...$ will $f_2(\cos (x))$ for example $f_2(\cos \frac \pi 3) = f_2(\frac 12)$.  We *could* say $f_2(g): x \mapsto f(g(x))$ but that is a very different concept then $f_1(g)= yellow$.

Comment: This becomes a question of "what exactly doe '$f(x)$' *mean*?"

Comment: Thanks @fleablood for your contributions. I'm not sure I follow the opening statement though: "*There is a very subtle difference between  and () and I don't think it'd be appropriate to ever write "=()"*" This is an expression I've seen in every textbook I've owned, which I thought was best read "f is a function of x", could you clarify why you feel this should never be used? Thanks for your time and help -- really appreciate it!

Comment: I've never seen the literal string "f = f(x)" ever.  If you write the function as $f$ or $f(x)$ you are emphasising aspects and you wouldn't really want to ever *mix* notation.  Are you sure you books actually say "eff equal sign f open parenthesis x close parenthesis"?  That string really wouldn't make any sense to me.   Even if I saw it I'd wonder *why* they'd say it. $f$ is the function as a math object and $f(x)$ is a expression of rule that describes the function.  Different perspectives.

Comment: @RaxAdaam, I've just returned to this question after a break and it seems to have much discussion. The mods may get a little irate if much more happens in theses comments as the comment section is not the place for them. If you want to talk more about this topic I would suggest  creating a room in https://chat.stackexchange.com/ and commenting the link to it here